# Setting postgresql password with Vagrant/Chef-solo

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm trying my hand at a bit of `chef-solo` for the first time on a Vagrant box for my open source project [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) so that contributors can more easily get a dev env up and running.

One thing I'm as of yet unable to achieve though is override the default password set by the `postgresql` recipe from [this cookbook](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/postgresql)

The docs mention setting the json config with something like:

```
postgresql: {
  password: {
    postgres: ''
  }
}
```

which I've done [here](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/blob/development/Vagrantfile#L68) but I can't seem to get it to override the default encrypted password that's set by the recipe.

I'm *brand new* (as of today) to chef/vagrant so I'm a bit lost as to where I should even look next.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get an error saying "You must set node['postgresql']['password']['postgres'] in chef-solo mode. For more information..." during the chef run? If not, the cookbook accepted your password and the error has to be somewhere else...

Comment: Me again, another seems to have similar problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195467/chef-and-postgres-how-do-i-specify-the-password#comment21628259_15296603

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cloned your gem and fired up Vagrant (but using a Debian Squeeze image I already downloaded and with all recipes disabled except `postgresql` and `postgresql::server`, and using PostgreSQL 8.4 instead of 9.1) and it seems that the empty password was a bad choice, using

```
  postgresql: {
    password: {
      postgres: 'foo'
    }
  }
```

works with the command `PGPASSWORD="foo" psql --username=postgres -h localhost` so I suspect that the empty password has some problems.

Comment: You can `ALTER USER` to set an empty password, but not log in with an empty password. It's effectively a disabled user. Attempting to log in with an empty password via a libpq client will result in a message like: `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`. Instead of setting an empty password, the user should generally be altering `pg_hba.conf` to use `peer` or `ident` auth or (for non-production use) `trust`.

Comment: turns out it was two issues... I wasn't explicitly setting the host (assumed localhost was default). Once I did that I got a `psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied` error, so it was obviously looking for one. @CraigRinger is right though, I should probably just set a `trust` auth since this is just a dev env to allow for no password